# Add new project to existing javadoc

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I have 2 projects for which I can create javadoc just fine using IntelliJ IDEA. However, if I create them in the same folder the docs are overwritten.
I would like to generate a single javadoc for both projects (and add more later on). How do I go about doing this in IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the separate projects into modules of a single project, and then use the "Whole project" option as the scope in the "Generate JavaDoc" dialog.

Comment: I would like to keep adding projects to my javadocs, so this would be a cumbersome task the furter in time I get. So basically it is not an option. So, am I doing it wrong? Should I just stick to seperate javadocs for seperate projects?

Comment: Why would this be a cumbersome task? IntelliJ IDEA supports multi-module projects very nicely, even if the number of modules is large. Adding a module to a project is as simple as right-clicking an .iml file in the Project view.

Comment: because I will be having multiple multi module projects, which I will turn into artifacts, and use the javadocs for documentation. I will probably never update those projects again for a long time and it would be a shame if i need to keep them all open just for the javadocs

Comment: The other option is to not use IntelliJ IDEA for generating JavaDocs at all, and to write an Ant/Maven/Gradle script that will invoke javadoc generation with the arguments that you need.